# Triggering a Blue Prism process from a button click in a web application page

Tags: web-services, rpa, blueprism

I need a way for the end user who has no blue prism knowledge to trigger a blue prism process.

Naturally, I thought of creating a button in an existing web application for the users to click on, such that they will trigger the blue prism process on demand.

I have exposed the blue prism process as a web service and have no idea how to proceed. How can I make a call to this web service from a button click?

Comment: what version of blue prism do you have? do you have service assist installed by any chance? that would solve your issue almost outright if you have it. if not ill write up some other alternatives

Comment: @DexterWhelan I have version 7.2.1. Nope, I don't have service assist installed.

Comment: sorry, apologies, i said service assist but i meant to say Interact. i was reading SA docs at the time. do you have this thing installed or access to this:
https://bpdocs.blueprism.com/bp-cloud/2023-1/interact/interact-home.htm?tocpath=Interact%7C_____0

if you have access id suggest this as an answer to your problem